# GCP CPU +100% when Scanning WP

Tags: wordpress

Moved my WordPress website from Vultr (2 vCPUs, 2gb) to Google Cloud E2 Medium (2 vCPUs, 4gb) & it cannot handle a Screaming Frog scan without crashing! What am I doing wrong? Never had the slightest issue with Vultr.

/usr/sbin/mysqld--daemonize--pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid is running at +100% when I scan the website.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add more details about your server stack.

If your WordPress is using Apache, just switch over to LEMP stack or use OpenLitespeed. Apache is great, easy to setup and can run almost anything. Plus you have Htaccess to tinker with your server settings. But, it can be a resource hog when it is poorly configured.

If you are not using Apache or wouldn't want to switch to Nginx PHP-FPM setup, ensure you have server side cache set up.

The easiest way to switch to LEMP stack is to use a Free control panel such as HestiaCP or Virtualmin. If you are a beginner, just go with HestiaCP since it is Lightweight and easier to use, otherwise go with Virtualmin.
Here is an [HestiaCP Full tutorial Video](https://youtu.be/y3dwiqGQ_cI) on YouTube.
[Here is a Virtualmin LEMP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NTQREVEcBb4&list=PLhhBJ0l9FKMOHUhWkKGL_R2-dfq4Ws_K0) stack playlist  on YouTube.